# LTspice simulation does not work like the real circuit

Tags: oscillator, ltspice, simulation, spice

I designed a Colpitts oscillator which uses a BC238B transistor.

When I set the circuit up on breadboard and PCB, it works flawlessly fine and I receive a sinusoidal signal at the output.

When I simulated the same circuit, it does work as it should. The output comes out very distorted.

I have to have a simulation working to put in my report but I cannot achieve it.

I played with the directive and settings and everything I can but it just does not work like the real world implementation.

Can you help?

Here is the circuit and the directive that I used:

[image: the circuit]

This is the directive:

```
.MODEL BC238 NPN (
+IS =1.8E-14 ISE=5.0E-14 NF =.9955 NE =1.46 BF =400
+BR =35.5 IKF=.14 IKR=.03 ISC=1.72E-13 NC =1.27 NR =1.005 RB =.56 RE =.6
+RC =.25 VAF=80 VAR=12.5 CJE=13E-12 TF =.64E-9 CJC=4E-12 TR =50.72E-9
+VJC=.54 MJC=.33 )
```

This circuit makes use of noise to start oscillating but I believe LTspice adds some noise to the analysis.

Comment: RE2 looks like it is too small in value - try raising it.

Comment: You need to show us exactly what you mean by "very distorted".

Comment: @Elliot Alderson it looks like distorted square wave with sharp spikes. I believe during the simulation the second transistor got out of forward active region and cuts off. By the way voltage at TP2 is sinusoidal but asymmetric and has high negative amplitude

Comment: Measure your transistors, breadboard and simulator, then compare their curves to see if they match or even come close. At the very least, modify the operating point in LTspice to be closer to the test case. Then measure the parasitics on your inductors/capacitors and try to model them just as accurately (this will likely require other schematics, solely for this purpose). Then try to model the exact inductances and parasitic capacitances of the connections/PCB/wires. Not lastly, try to at least add series resistance and parallel capacitance for the sources. Then try simulating again.